How can interpret an error message in google sheets?
Is there a way to output the specific Error Message such as the "Imported content is empty." seen here.
.
Ideally, I'd like to change a cell from just saying "N/A" to a specific message based on the specific error message rather than just the error type.
All the googling I've done just tells me there's ways to change for the error type, but nothing I've found that interprets the message itself.
Adding further clarity: the specific Error message can be one of many and is not limited to "Imported content is empty." In this specific case, I'm using =IMPORTXML(). Another common message is "Resource at URL not found." I'm ideally looking for a way to differentiate between error messages such that I can highlight the cell based on the specific error message or have the error message itself be placed into a cell itself.

Did you try =IFNA(YourFormuala,"Imported content is empty.")?

I appreciate the response. This isn't quite what I'm looking for, as the error message I used as an example isn't the only possible error message. I added further clarity in the original post.

Then you may combine each type of error inside IFS() function.

This is probably impossible using formulas as the error message is metadata that cannot be 'seen' by formulas; the most granular error handling that is possible with a formula is (as you have already mentioned) using ERROR.TYPE which is limited to the 8 categories of error possible in a sheet.
